# Accessing volatile varibales concurrently in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile

While reading [this blog post](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#pitfall-acquire-release-order-wrong) I'm failing to understand section 3.6 and 3.7.

Code in 3.6:

```
@JCStressTest
@State
public class AcquireOrderWrong {
    int x;
    volatile int g;

    @Actor
    public void actor1() {
        g = 1;
        x = 1;
    }

    @Actor
    public void actor2(IntResult2 r) {
        r.r1 = x;
        r.r2 = g;
    }
}
```

Code in 3.7:

```
@JCStressTest
@Outcome(id = "1, 0", expect = Expect.FORBIDDEN,  desc = "Happens-before violation")
@Outcome(             expect = Expect.ACCEPTABLE, desc = "All other cases are acceptable.")
@State
public class SafePublication {

    int x;
    volatile int ready;

    @Actor
    public void actor1() {
        x = 1;
        ready = 1;
    }

    @Actor
    public void actor2(IntResult2 r) {
        r.r1 = ready;
        r.r2 = x;
    }
}
```

In 3.6 it's say that 1,0 is an impossibile outcome due to *it is a naked data race* which I (maybe wrongly) interpret as *due to the fact that unrelated operations can be reordered on execution this could happend*.

But if this is the case shouldn't the example in 3.7 suffer of the same problem ?

Comment: You should copy the code you're talking about into the question. Otherwise the question would become useless if the original source was removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 3.7, `ready` is a `volatile` variable, according to the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html)

> This means that changes to a volatile variable are always visible to
>   other threads. What's more, it also means that when a thread reads a
>   volatile variable, it sees not just the latest change to the volatile,
>   but also the side effects of the code that led up the change.

In `actor()`, you set `ready` after setting `x`. So, when you read `ready` in method `actor2`, JVM can gurantee that `x=1` is also visible, which avoids `(1, 0)` as output.